# How do i align an image with text in an HStack?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a view that is a rectangle with text and images inside. This is done in a VStack. At the bottom of the VStack, I have an HStack where I have a small image and a number next to it. These need to be centred aligned but I can't seem to make that happen.

The image is higher up than the number. I need them to be at an equal height.

```
VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {

                                    Image("ProductLogo")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                        .clipped()
                                        .padding()
                                        .layoutPriority(1)


                                    Text("Text Here")
                                    .font(.title2)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                                    .padding(.leading, 5)
                                    .padding(.trailing, 5)
                                    .padding(.bottom, 5)


                                Text("Subtitle")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                    .lineLimit(2)
                                    .padding(1)
                                    
                                    //HERE IS WHAT NEEDS TO BE ALIGNED
                                    HStack {
                                        
                                        Image("CoinImage")
                                            .resizable()
                                            .frame(width: 35, height: 35, alignment: .center)
                                    
                                    Text("500")
                                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                                        .padding(.top,20)
   
                                    }    
                        //END OF HSTACK
                                }
```

Here is an image of the VStack:

[image]

The 500 should be level with the coin image

Comment: Please attach an image of exactly the output you want.

Comment: Just added a photo @TrupeshVaghasiya

Comment: Okay, I have added my answer please check it.  If it works for you then approve it. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/73555910/9331686

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove padding from `Text("500")` and set to `HStack`

Please try with below code and let me know it's works for you

```
VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            
            Image("ProductLogo")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .clipped()
                .padding()
                .layoutPriority(1)
            
            
            Text("Text Here")
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding(.leading, 5)
                .padding(.trailing, 5)
                .padding(.bottom, 5)
            
            
            Text("Subtitle")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .lineLimit(2)
                .padding(1)
            
            //HERE IS WHAT NEEDS TO BE ALIGNED
            HStack {
                
                Image("CoinImage")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 35, height: 35, alignment: .center)
                
                Text("500")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                
            }.padding(.top, 10)
            //END OF HSTACK
        }
```